# Is it possible to get pregnant through natural means in space?

Tags: medical, life, astrobiology

The Russians did some early testing with rats [(Packing for Mars: The Curious Science of Life in the Void, By Mary Roach pg 245](http://books.google.com/books?id=cg0ZR4rzzQoC&pg=PA244&dq=zero%20gravity%20pregnancy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-DfsUdDYGbbe4AOz2oDADA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=pregnancy&f=false)) and natural means did not result in pregnancy. Later testing shipped pregnant rats into space, where some health issues developed.

NASA research indicates that female astronauts have given birth after flying in space, some difficulties in achieving pregnancy are reported, but attributed to age, secondary to delaying attempts while pursing careers. ([Principles of Clinical Medicine for Space Flight edited by Michael R. Barratt, Sam Lee Pool page 384](http://books.google.com/books?id=QYrH9P0iPb8C&pg=PA387&dq=zero%20gravity%20pregnancy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-DfsUdDYGbbe4AOz2oDADA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=pregnancy&f=false))

Is there any research on mammal impregnation occurring naturally in space?

**Edit**, clarify that this question is about the impregnation --> Egg and Sperm join, Cells divide and attach to the uterus; the 1979 Russian study indicates there were problems at this stage.

Comment: This question is awesome. The easy answer is yes. I know of some research on this topic as well ... I am really looking forward to a **good** answer for this one. Please do not speculate, read the studies first and enjoy them!

Comment: If someone cares to go on the wild goose chase through Slashdot archives, you'll find the source: Yes, you can get pregnant during or after space flight, but the offspring will be infertile, at least after lengthy space travel. The space radiation damages the egg cells in such way. That was cited as a major roadblock in settling Mars.

Comment: @SF This question is about the impregnation, sperm meets egg and implants succussfully the 1979 rat studies indicate that there was a flaw at this point.  I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I think this question could be seen as just one of many on a more general topic of effects of non-terrestrial environments on the reproductive viability of terrestrial life. Non-terrestrial environments would include LEO, interplanetary or interstellar space, as well as non-terrestrial surfaces, so would include zero-G and reduced G, as well as different radiation environments. It would cover not just "the act" in space, or effects on reproductive processes during exposure to said environments, but also prior "space" exposure on such processes initiated after return to Earth.

Comment: They fly a pregnancy test kit on the ISS....so someone is not ruling it out.

http://www.spaceref.com/iss/medical/4041.pregnancy.pdf

Comment: @OrganicMarble  - oh man. That is such a delicious little fact, i wish it it stood out a little more...

Comment: Related question [Why is there a pregnancy test kit on the ISS?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/)

Comment: Just my opinion but I would say that WE HAVE NO valid data to suggest an answer here. I am unaware of ANY SPACE MISSION, were the subjects were exposed to both POSITIVE GRAVITY and PROTECTED FROM RADIATION. Nothing about your question suggest constraints.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Dr. Tore Straume](http://spacebiosciences.arc.nasa.gov/staff/tore-straume) of NASA's BioSciences Division actually published a paper on this very topic. Titled: "[Radiation Hazards and the Colonization of Mars: Brain, Body, Pregnancy, In-Utero Development, Cardio, Cancer, Degeneration"](http://journalofcosmology.com/Mars124.html)

The study conducted by them concluded that the Space radiation negatively affects Male fertility. The Cosmic Radiation during travel is supposed to so high that it can significantly decrease the male sperm count and they would also sterilize human fetus. The only solution to that seems to be better shielding from cosmic radiation.

> The critical health effect (most radiosensitive) for human colonization of Mars may turn out to be infertility in women resulting from radiation exposure in utero. Although direct human data are not available for this effect, studies in non-human primates have found that oocytes are extremely radiosensitive during gestation, i.e., 50% killed following only 0.07 Sv of chronic tritium beta rays (similar in biological effectiveness to x rays and GCR protons).

Also another obstacle or problem seems to be the effect of the lack of gravity on the bone development process.

Comment: Noting that you get up to about 0.1 to 0.3mSv  per year of Cosmic Rays on Earth [src](http://www.epa.gov/radiation/understand/perspective.html), (and about 2.4mSv to 6.4mSv total radiation), but an estimated 400 to 900mSv per year [src](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_threat_from_cosmic_rays) in space, that really puts the 70mSv dosage in the test to the "over what timeframe" question, as  it's known that over time, some immune response does handle low-level exposure changes.

Comment: @aramis Is your data using the best shielding available to humans to use? Or is it shiedling that meet the mission requirements which the data you collected may just be a add on and not taken into consideration

Comment: The data was NASA's for onboard the Apollo, Shuttle, ISS and Skylab data. None of which are best available to use, because such is too expensive to fly, because it's massive.

Answer (score 8):

Strictly speaking, the answer to your question is **yes**. As I have explained in answer to a related question ([What animals, if any, have reproduced in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4513/what-animals-if-any-have-reproduced-in-space)), nematodes are able to experience a full reproduction cycle in space. Nematodes *are* considered pregnant at a point in this cycle, and their pregnancy does meet your definition:

> Egg and Sperm join, Cells divide and attach to the uterus

Now, obviously nematodes are not mammals, and though some are ovoviviparous, the species observed in space is not. I am not aware of any mammals that have been observed to get pregnant in space.

Answer (score 3):

Another attempt to figure out for vertebrates is to be conducted on the [Foton-M4 spacrecraft](http://en.samspace.ru/products/satellites_of_scientific_purpose/ka_foton_m_4/) this summer.

Check out the google translation of the flight experiment program:
http://biosputnik.imbp.ru/science_f.html

The *Gecko-F4* experiment states as its first objectives:

> - to create the conditions for sexual behavior, copulation and
>     breeding of geckos in the orbital experiment;
> - to record on camera the sexual behavior of Phelsuma ornata and possible oviposition, and
>     to maximize the probability of survival for eggs that can be laid
>     during the experiment;

Let's wait just a couple of months.

Comment: Do you have an update to this answer?

Comment: Nothing has been published yet, afaict. The same number of geckos have returned to earth. All geckos have died just a couple of days before returning, they say. But were some of them pregnant? Not clear.

Comment: The fresh issue of Novosti Kosmonavtiki states the geckos were not pregnant on autopsy :-(