# Laws and Treaties for Activities in Outer Space

Tags: law

What are the laws and treaties that govern activities in outer space?

Comment: Some additional insight might be available at [Jurisdiction over crime in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/683/12102) and [What if any US laws apply on the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8575/12102) *and some additional insight here might be beneficial there as well!*

Comment: It seems that some the answers to this question provide the same treaties, yet indicate different years. Can someone clarify?

Comment: @Krumuvecis if you spot some differences then it will be most helpful if you leave a comment under each post listing the specific differences. That way each post's author will receive a notification of your comment and their attention will be called to the issue. Chances are low that either answer's author will see your comment here. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 6):

The five main treaties governing activities in outer space are:

- the 1967 [Outer Space Treaty](https://www.unoosa.org/oosa/en/ourwork/spacelaw/treaties/outerspacetreaty.html),
- the 1967 astronaut [Rescue Agreement](https://www.unoosa.org/pdf/gares/ARES_22_2345E.pdf),
- the 1972 [Liability Convention](https://www.unoosa.org/pdf/gares/ARES_26_2777E.pdf),
- the 1974 [Registration Convention](https://www.unoosa.org/pdf/gares/ARES_29_3235E.pdf) and
- the 1979 [Moon Convention](https://www.unoosa.org/pdf/gares/ARES_34_68E.pdf).

Manuals currently being discussed are:

- Manual on International Law Applicable to Military Uses of Outer
  Space ([MILAMOS](https://www.mcgill.ca/milamos/)), launched in 2016, to developed through Mc Gill
  University in Canada,  to develop a widely-accepted manual clarifying
  the fundamental rules applicable to the military use of outer space
  in peacetime.
- The [Woomera Manual](https://law.adelaide.edu.au/woomera/), to apply when armed conflict occurs.
- The [Tallinn Manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallinn_Manual) on the International Law Applicable to Cyber
  Warfare may also be applicable if cyber warfare is conducted in
  outer space.

*Additional reading:*

[What is the Woomera Manual and how might it help stop a war in space?](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-11-12/woomera-manual-rulebook-to-clarify-space-war-law/12869492)

[A guide to ensure everyone plays by the same military rules in space: the Woomera Manual](https://theconversation.com/a-guide-to-ensure-everyone-plays-by-the-same-military-rules-in-space-the-woomera-manual-115146)

[The Woomera Manual](https://www.spacelegalissues.com/space-law-the-woomera-manual/)

[The Tallinn Manual and Space Law](https://www.spacelegalissues.com/the-tallinn-manual-and-space-law/)

[Tallinn Manual 2.0 on the International Law Applicable to Cyber Operations](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/law/humanitarian-law/tallinn-manual-20-international-law-applicable-cyber-operations-2nd-edition?format=PB)

[Military Space Operations and International Law](https://www.justsecurity.org/68815/military-space-operations-and-international-law/)

Answer (score 4):

The major international agreements include:

- [The 1967 Outer Space Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty)
- [The 1967 Agreement on Rescue and Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_Agreement)
- [The 1972 Space Liability Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Liability_Convention)
- [The 1974 Convention on Registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registration_Convention)

In addition, there's [the 1979 Moon Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_Treaty), which hasn't been widely ratified, so lacks any real legal force.

The [Commercial Space Launch Competitiveness Act of 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Space_Launch_Competitiveness_Act_of_2015) allows space mining by US businesses.

Answer (score 2):

There are also a raft of domestic laws, depending on what country you are operating from. Those tend to relate to things like safety of operations, avoiding radio frequency interference, and national security controls (e.g. export controls, restrictions on Earth imaging, etc.)